Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 X11, how to listen on TCP, and start with access control disabled
This is for Ubuntu (kubuntu) 24.04 and also 22.04. (I was able to find a similar question but relating to a decade old version of Ubuntu.)
The use case is that it is just me on a LAN, and I have no need for X11 security, and would like to just be able to send X11 apps to whichever display without issue. So:

What is the right way to enable TCP listening (which is disabled by default)?
How do you start the X server with access control disabled (to avoid having to have e.g. xhost + in a login script)?


Put another way, Xorg is started with the switches -auth and -nolisten tcp, as you can see by cating /proc/.../cmdline. I would like to replace these with -ac and -listen tcp instead, but can't find where these are set.
